# VB.NET to connec to MDB file using windows default ODBC JET driver

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-connection, oledb, visual-studio-2022

I am building a Windows Winforms Desktop Application using VB.NET 6.0.5, Visual Basic, and Visual Studio Community 2022.

I used to connect to ACCDB File using **Microsoft Access Database Engine**.

It's working well in the development machine, but when I try to deploy to a fresh installation of a Windows 10 x64 machine; I have to let the setup download and install the ACE engine.

I want to reduce the prerequisites as much as possible, as the end-users already have to download and install the .NET 6 Runtime.

I found out that all versions of Windows come by default with **Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)** and I want to use that.

[image: Drivers in Fresh copy of Windows 10 x64]

The driver location is:  `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

I think if someone installed Office it might update the driver to a different **Jet.OLEDB** version.

So my question is:

How to check the current **Jet.OLEDB** driver's version and what would be the connection string?

My current connection string is:

```
Dim cStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb;User ID=Admin;Password=123;"
```

But still, it's giving that **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Provider is not registered**.

[image: Driver not registred]

I know that ACE Engine and ACCDB work better but it's enough for me to use JET and MDB.

Please help!

Thank you

**Update: 20/5/2022**

***Things that I tried but with no success:***

- I compiled the application to target **x86** as it's said in many references that `Jet.OLEDB` doesn't support **x64**.
- I tried `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.10.0`.

Comment: Didn't you say you want to use the ODBC Driver? The connection string would something like `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=Database.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=123;` -- There could also be the `.accdb` ODBC driver, named `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` -- The JET OleDb Provider is also always there, 32 bit only.

Comment: If you run 64-bit, [that's why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/jet-odbc-driver-available-32-bit-version?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: @Jimi I tried to set it to 32 bit, and I used your suggested connection string, but I got this error: **An OLEDB Provider was not specified in the connection string. An example would be, Provider=SQLOLEDB;.**

Comment: Are you using `System.Data.Odbc` or `System.Data.OleDb`? I.e., do you want to use ODBC or JET OleDb?

Comment: @Jimi I am using `Imports System.Data.OleDb`

Comment: So, you're **not** trying to use ODBC, you're using OLE DB with the ancient JET.OLEDB provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you wondering what the connection string should be?
Let VS build it for you.

(you don't want to hand code, or type in connection strings anyway - and you don't have to).

So, in setting for your VS project, then here:

[image]

So, let click on that [...] and build the connection using JET (as opposed to ACE).

However, your issue/problem is that NOW vs2022 is x64 bits (first version to be that way).

I'm running 2019, so it will STILL test and VERIFY a x32 bit connection. I suspect that vs2022 WILL NOT pass the "test" button, but you STILL can use it to build the conneciton.

So, in above, we start the connection wizard, - hit change for the defaulted sql server, and we now have this choice:

[image]

Ok, we selected Access, but what about JET vs ACE.

Well, click on advanced - this:

[image]

And now we can (get to) choose the provider.

this:

[image]

So, you can choose jet or ACE.

choosing jet, then we now back to here:

[image]

Now BECAUSE I am running vs2019, then my test connection WILL work!!! - for you, it probably will not. So, the test connection button for you - you can try it, but EVEN if it gives a fail message, your connection is still ok.

This:

[image]

Ok, at this point, we are done.

We now in code can use the above connection in our code. Say like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TestJET)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels", conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            Dim strMSG As String =
                "There are " & rstData.Rows.Count & " Hotels in the database " & vbCrLf &
                "The first Hotel is " & rstData.Rows(0).Item("HotelName")

            MsgBox(strMSG, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Table info")

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And we get this:

[image]

Now, I suppose I could look at the connection string - but I never really do that - I always let the system build that for me.

I get this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test\Rides_be.mdb
```

As you noted, MAKE sure your project is set to x32. However, since you running vs2022, then the connection builder should work, but you HAVE to run your project to test that connection, I don't think in vs2022, you can use "test" connection.

On the other hand, since most of office (and even Access ACE is x64 bits?). Then if you build a connection using x64 bit ACE, then your test connection button should work.

Comment: @albert-d-kallal, Thank you so much! It worked like charm. I needed to update a few things though to fit VS 2022. I updated your answer. Please review.

I have a question related to your answer. If the end-users somehow updated their JET version; will it still work? Or is it always `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` in all Windows Version and never change? Do I need to check the installed version first? Thank you again! It really saved a lot of time!

Comment: Hum, the problem is that if you used advanced, and then enter the password, then yes the password does save. I don't think entering the password in that main box ever worked. And now this might be a vs2022 vs previous issues.  As far as I know, you never could enter the password in the main box, but you always had to hit advanced, and enter the password at that point. You have to try that in vs2022, but I suspect it will ALSO work. (so enter of Admin, and password has to occur when you hit advanced tab, and then it will persit, and you get a warning about password is exposed as plain text

Comment: When I say advanced tab, that is the same tab where you can select the JET or ACE provider. Entering the user + password in that location, then yes the uid/password is saved, and you can see it in plain text in the connection when you do that.   I suppose one could mention that is HOW you ALWAYS for a very long time have to enter the uid/password, and you can't enter nor save the user/password in the main box where the [x] Save my password box is. But, yes, to save, you do that in advanced tab, and it does save, and does work.

Comment: As for end users updating JET? Well, it been installed as part of the windows OS since windows 98SE (that is pre-windows xp days). So, they can't really update JET, and even if they decide to install ACE, both JET and ACE happy live and exist on the computer at the same time. So, if some update occures to JET, jet will still remain installed on the computer, and installing ACE does not effect this fact (JET remains installed).

Comment: @albert-d-kallal, Thank you so much for spending time to answer! I tried to enter the password in the Advanced tab, but there is no place to put the password. I think the only way to do that in VS 2022 is to add it manually in the Project Settings tab. I reported the [bug to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-connection-string-builder-dosnt-sav/10049306)

Comment: Actually, try the advanced tab. The main panel and entry of uid/password never worked. This is a bit of  UI face plant in VS. But, if you hit advanced, and enter the pw in the advanced settings where you select the JET/ACE, then the password does get saved. The UI always been that way - and is confusing to say the least.

Comment: @albert-d-kallal, As I said in my previous comment; there is no place for password. Please see this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/mLtKsnC.jpeg). Thank you

Comment: @albert-d-kallal, You seem to be professional. Can you please share how you do connection string encryption?

Comment: I as a general rule don't. For web based then of course there are options to encrypt the connection strings in web.config. (and such code is 100% server side). For desktop and Access I never had to encrypt. I suppose you could write a routine to encrypt the settings at deploy time, and then each setting would have to be wrapped around one extra function. Since it's on desktop then spy++ and other memory tools can fetch such values after you decrypted anyway.  Unless you prompt users for a logon then you don't have many options. The general "settings" for company name etc. could be encrypted

Comment: So, you could adopt some encrypting routine - there are boatloads of examples as such. I guess it would at least prevent "easy" change or modifying of the settings tab, and the many settings typical applications have - including connection strings. But, if using sql server, then we using windows auth, or we prompt the user for their sql logon.